# Seemingly .......... crowds of tourist invade our cities in the summer

Tags: exam-questions

Which option fits best in the following question?

> Seemingly .......... crowds of tourist invade our cities in the
>   summer.

1. innumerable
2. endless
3. countless
4. unbound

Comment: Can you kindly provide what are your thoughts regarding this? (By adding your thoughts about your inquiries, you provide us with a 'better' perspective, you know..)

Comment: But what is your language question? Looking up definitions might answer your question. If you did, then you need to add details as to what needs further explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your choices work except **unbound** or **unbounded**.

The main point of your description is the uncountable volume of tourists

> innumerable crowds of tourists
>   endless crowds of tourists
>   countless crowds of tourists

**Unbounded** in a mathematical sense means not limit, but when used as an adjective for crowds could be interpreted as **unfettered**, tourists who were not tied up.

Comment: Can we say "endless crowds of tourists" is the most common ?